# How do I push coordinates from a pandas dataframe to into a List?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of x y coordiantes like so;

```
import pandas as pd
coords = pd.read_csv("covariates/coords.csv")
print coords.head(n=5)

Coordinates
               x               y
0  434483.347684  1873512.572689
1  433703.881013  1874208.610947
2  433087.930224  1874647.987855
3  432620.418522  1875015.801780
4  432623.666835  1875078.630570
```

I want to push the coords into a list for the purpose of making a point shapefile, à la [this quesiton](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16122/how-to-create-a-shapefile-in-arcgis-10-using-arcpy)

How to I export the coordinates from the data frame into the list style seen below?

```
ptList =[[1873512.572689,1873512.572689],[1873512.572689, 1873512.572689],[1873512.572689, 1873512.572689]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use could use `df.values.tolist()` ?

```
In [21]: df.values.tolist()
Out[21]:
[[434483.34768400004, 1873512.572689],
 [433703.88101300003, 1874208.610947],
 [433087.93022399995, 1874647.987855],
 [432620.418522, 1875015.8017799999],
 [432623.66683500004, 1875078.63057]]
```

`df.values` creates an NumPy array and you could call `tolist()` to access list of lists.